# Using lambda to remove items in dropdownlist WHERE first 2 characters exists in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, drop-down-menu

Web.config:

```
<add key="blacklistVendors" value="01,02"/>
```

aspx

```
string[] blacklistVendors= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blacklistVendors"].Split(',');

ddlVendor.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Value == "It").ToList().ForEach(i => ddlVendor.Items.Remove(i));
```

I would like to change the i.Value into checking if the value's first 2 letters exist in the blacklistVendors string array. If it exists, it will remove the item in the dropdownlist.

Here's something that I came up with, but it's having an error:

```
ddlTicketVendor.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(vendorSeries.Any(i => i.Value.Substring(0, 2))).ToList().ForEach(i => ddlTicketVendor.Items.Remove(i));
```

It seems i.Value is not accessible when I put vendorSeries.Any inside Where

Errors:

> Error 39  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to
>   'System.Func'
>
> Error 38  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expression the compiler is complaining about:

```
vendorSeries.Any(i => i.Value.Substring(0, 2))
```

You cannot pass it to `Where`, because it is not a `Func<ListItem,bool>`

Here is how you fix it:

```
ddlTicketVendor.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Select(i => new {Item = i, Prefix = i.Value.Substring(0, 2)})
    .Where(i => vendorSeries.Any(s => i.Prefix == s))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => ddlTicketVendor.Items.Remove(i.Item));
```

Selecting an anonymous pair makes sure that we compute `i.Value.Substring(0, 2)` once per item. The above code assumes that `vendorSeries` is a collection of two-character prefixes agains which we compare items. You can further simplify this code by constructing a `HashSet<string>` of the banned prefixes:

```
var bannedPrefix = new HashSet<string>(vendorSeries);
ddlTicketVendor.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(i => !bannedPrefix.Contains(i.Value.Substring(0, 2)))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => ddlTicketVendor.Items.Remove(i));
```